# Higher order component not passing props

Tags: reactjs

I have the following HOC:

```
render() {
    return (
        <div>
            <ComposedComponent {...this.props} />
        </div>
    );
}
```

and the component it's rendering:

```
class Banner extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
...
...
}
}
```

Using logging I discovered that props that exist in the HOC, are not being passed to the child component.
(If I do `console.log` in the child component's constructor for `props` it would just be `{}` whereas in the HOC I would get the correct result)

This usually happens only when I'm on the child page in my browser, after refreshing the page.

Why does it happen?

Comment: Can you post the whole code for parent and child component?

Comment: Looking at it a bit more, seems like i have to use `componentWillReceiveProps`... i just need help with why this is happening and how to implement it correctly.

Comment: Have you tried `<ComposedComponent data={...this.props} />` in HOC and `console.log(this.props.data)` in child component ?

Comment: Yeah that's exactly what i did, the `console.log` sometimes returned `{}`, but like i pointed out in my answer, i think it's because the child component had rendered before the props were passed to it.

Answer (score 0):

Alright, i just had to add the following to my child component code: (i guess the parent component's props were coming down only after it had finished rendering)

```
    componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
        if (this.props !== nextProps) {
            this.setState(nextProps)
        }
    }
```

Comment: This method is deprecated and should no longer be used. See https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#unsafe_componentwillreceiveprops

Answer (score 0):

It's likely that the Component lifecycle method you should be using is `componentDidMount()` - but it's very difficult to say for certain without your complete code.

Also, you may omit the constructor if your JS build chain supports the class fields proposal and all you're doing is setting the initial state of the component - [see here for more info](https://overreacted.io/why-do-we-write-super-props/). Again, difficult to say for certain without your complete code. It's possible that some of your constructor logic should be moved to `componentDidMount()`.

If an issue only happens after a refresh, it probably has to do with logic that runs when the component first mounts, but doesn't run simply when the props of the component update.