# Passing props to components rendered dynamically from object

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-props, higher-order-components

I have an object full of components:

```js
const Icons = {
   // commonly used darksky icon names
   "clear-day": <ClearDayIcon />,
   "clear-night": <ClearNightIcon />,
   "rain": <RainMediumIcon />,
   "snow": <SnowIcon />,
   "sleet": <RainHeavyIcon />,
   "wind": <WindyDayIcon />,
   // etc..
}
```

Each component is really just an svg wrapped as a react component.  But I need it to receive props from the place where its called, especially the `className` prop.

What I want to be able to do is call these components from my other components in the following manner:

```
<WeatherIcon icon={icon} className="some-class" />
```

Where the icon prop will determine which icon component is chosen.  So I tried this:

```
const WeatherIcon = props => Icons[ props.icon ]
```

So this works partially, as I can write `<WeatherIcon icon={'clear-night'} />`, and the correct component is rendered.  However, there's no way to pass any other props from my `WeatherIcon` component down through each `Icon`.  For example, writing `<WeatherIcon icon={'clear-night'} className="some-class" />` clearly does not pass the `className` prop (or any other prop) down through to each individual component.  I tried doing something like this:

```js
const Icons = {
   "clear-day": props => <ClearDayIcon {...props} />,
   "clear-night": props => <ClearNightIcon {...props} />,
   // etc..
}
```

But this doesn't work because now I'm returning a `Component` rather than a `<Component />`.  I saw the solutions in the question [Passing props to dynamically loaded components](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57763592/higher-order-component-not-passing-props), but these all suggest calling the component like `{ Icons['clear-day'](className: 'some-class', anotherProp: 'some-prop') }`.  I feel like this is not very elegant.  There must be a way to write it as a `<WeatherIcon icon={'some-icon'} className={'some-class'} someProp={'some-prop'} />`, and have the props filter down correctly.  (I do realize that all the props would filter all the way down to my SVG component - that's fine).  I feel like theres a higher order component waiting to be written here, but right now its eluding me.

Thanks for reading

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out that this works too - write the object containing the components as a function of props, which returns the object.  Then you can use a `{...props}` in each component:

```js
const Icons = props => ({
   "clear-day": <ClearDayIcon {...props} />,
   "clear-night": <ClearNightIcon {...props} />,
   "rain": <RainMediumIcon {...props} />,
   etc.
})
```

Then the wrapper component looks like this:

```js
const WeatherIcon = props => Icons(props)[ props.icon ]
```

Pretty simple - I knew I was close.  I'm not sure if this is considered a higher order component (HOC).  It *is* a component that returns another component based on its props, with new props attached.  Does that count as an HOC?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not 100% sure about if this will fulfill your requirement but I would probably try something like this;

```js
const Icons = {
   "clear-day": ClearDayIcon,
   "clear-night": ClearNightIcon,
   "rain": RainMediumIcon,
   "snow": SnowIcon,
   "sleet": RainHeavyIcon,
   "wind": WindyDayIcon,
   // etc..
}

const Icon = ({icon, ...rest}) => {
    const IconComponent = Icons[icon]

    if(!IconComponent) {
        // Or throw an exception maybe.
        // At least print some console warnings in development env.
        return null;
    }

    return <IconComponent {...rest} />
}
```

With this way, you can select one of your Icon components and pass any prop to it.
And when you want to use it, you can use it like this;

```js
// ...
<Icon icon="clear-day" className="some-class" />
// ...
```